# What does the "G" and "V" in penicillin V and penicillin G stand for?

Tags: terminology, antibiotics

I've been looking for a convincing explanation for the designation penicillin G and V. The answers I've found includes G as in "gold standard" and "V" as in "viscus" but they're not sourced and not especially credible explanations.

Comment: The first discovered penicillins were designated I, II, III in Britain and F, G, X in America. I can't find what the letters stand for. Could it be that, as they were determining the composition of natural penicillin (which originally referred to the Penicillium culture supernatant), they designated compounds alphabetically and these letters happened to correspond to penicillins?

Comment: Penicillin V is synthetic and, according to [this book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=i4_FZHmzjzwC&pg=PA121#v=onepage&q=penicillin%20v&f=false), was named V for vertraulich (German for confidential).